# How can I read serial port data into a dynamically-sized buffer?

Tags: rust, serial-port, buffer

I'm using this method as part of a WebSocket client implementation to read data from a serial port and send it to the server. I had to wrap the port in `Arc<Mutex<_>>` because I needed to share it with other methods in order to write to the serial port upon receiving a WebSocket message.

I'm using a 128 byte `u8` buffer to store the data; is there any way to make the buffer dynamically-sized? Wrapping in `Arc<Mutex<_>>` is a must.

```rust
extern crate env_logger;
extern crate ws;
use std::thread;
use ws::{listen, CloseCode, Handler, Handshake, Message, Result, Sender};

fn on_open(&mut self, _: Handshake) -> Result<(), ws::Error> {
    let port_handle: Arc<Mutex<SystemPort>> = self.port_handle.clone();
    let out: Sender = self.out.clone();
    thread::spawn(move || {
        // read_from_serial(&mut port);
        let mut buffer = [0u8; 128];
        let mut msg: String;
        loop {
            let read_result: Result<usize, std::io::Error>;
            {
                read_result = port_handle
                    .lock()
                    .expect("Access port handle")
                    .read(&mut buffer);
            }
            if read_result.is_ok() {
                msg = buffer_to_string(&buffer);
                buffer = [0u8; 128];
                println!("Client sending message: '{}'", msg);
                out.send(msg).expect("Forward COM message to server");
            }
        }
    });
    Ok(())
}
```

Edit: This is the same code using read_to_string instead of read. The string length is completely dynamic, but the only problem is that read_result is always Err(Custom { kind: TimedOut, error: StringError("Operation timed out") }) here. As a temporary fix, I decided to leave the Result unused and used msg.len() > 0 to test for a new serial message.

```rust
extern crate env_logger;
extern crate ws;
use std::thread;
use ws::{listen, CloseCode, Handler, Handshake, Message, Result, Sender};

fn on_open(&mut self, _: Handshake) -> Result<(), ws::Error> {
            let port_handle = self.port_handle.clone();
            let out = self.out.clone();
            thread::spawn(move || {
                // read_from_serial(&mut port);
                let mut buffer = String::new();
                let mut msg;
                loop {
                    {
                        port_handle
                            .lock()
                            .expect("Access port handle")
                            .read_to_string(&mut buffer);
                        msg = format!("{}", buffer);
                    }
                    if msg.len() > 0 {
                        buffer.clear();
                        println!("Client sending message: '{}'", msg);
                        out.send(msg).expect("Forward COM message to server");
                    }
                }
            });
            Ok(())
        }
```

Edit: Ive included the following minimal example and removed all other unnecessary code.

```rust
extern crate env_logger;
extern crate serial;
use serial::prelude::*;
use std::io::Read;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let client = thread::spawn(move || {
        // setting up serial port
        let mut port = serial::open("/dev/tnt0").expect("Open serial port");
        let new_timeout = Duration::from_millis(1000);
        port.set_timeout(new_timeout).expect("Set port timeout");

        // setting up buffer
        let mut buffer = String::new();

        // looping to continuously read serial data
        loop {
            // unused Result returned by read_to_string
            // because when used, it always is an Err variant
            // `Custom { kind: TimedOut, error: StringError("Operation timed out") }`
            port.read_to_string(&mut buffer);
            // using string length to test for valid data instead of using Ok/Err
            if buffer.len() > 0 {
                println!("Client sending message: '{}'", buffer);
                // clearing buffer for next iteration
                buffer.clear();
            }
        }
    });

    // Wait for the worker threads to finish what they are doing
    let _ = client.join();
    println!("All done.")
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what your problem is. Why do you need a "dynamically-sized" buffer? Why don't you just read 64 (arbitrary number) and push those bytes into a `Vec`?

Comment: @hellow Because if the message length is above buffer size, it would end up being split into 2 or more messages and sent out individually. I imagine a more dynamic structure would handle things differently.

Comment: @hellow the message payload are commands that are sent out to a robot, so it is crucial to handle such cases.

Comment: Please edit your question to include all the crates and type definitions that are needed to compile the code. I suspect [`read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string) is what you're looking for but I don't know what `SystemPort` is. If possible, remove parts of the code that are irrelevant to your question. For instance, is `ws` really part of the problem, or could you just delete the `out` part and demonstrate the serial port problem alone?

Comment: *I'm using a 128 bit u8 buffer* — no, you are using a 128 **byte** buffer. These two values are 8x different from each other.

Comment: @trentcl read_to_string is very helpful, but it introduced one problem. The read_result is always an error: Err(Custom { kind: TimedOut, error: StringError("Operation timed out") })

Comment: @trentcl I've updated the question to reflect using read_to_string.

Comment: Is the use of WebSockets and threads *really necessary* to debug this problem, or could you reduce it to a small program that *only* tries to read from the serial port? If you can't eliminate *anything* extraneous, then in order to help us debug it, you need to provide the server code as well as the rest of whatever struct `on_open` is defined on and a `main` function or failing test that demonstrates the problem. The [tag:rust] [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) has more suggestions for creating a [mre].

Comment: @trentcl I've just edited my question and added that. Please review the last code block in my question.